# How to assign object to variable in Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I am trying to assigned a variable from a search object :

```
$tes = $ListLookup.Items | where-object {$_.title -eq "TEST"} | sort Title | FT ID
```

So the above brings back the ID of the item I want. But I want to assign that ID number "4" to a variable.

So I can use it in `$listLookup = $List.GetItemById(4)` as I am trying to get information via that code.

Hope that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, to get item ID from filter list, you don't need FT(format).

```
#Set config variables
$baseUrl="http://sp:12001/"
$listName ="test"

#Get Web and List Objects
$web = Get-SPWeb $baseUrl
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]
$tes = $list.Items | where-object {$_.title -eq "test"} | sort ID
$ID=$tes[0].ID
```